# MSSQL query several date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query data for several date ranges. This is what I wrote:

```
Select Datetime, Round(value,3) As v
From myTable
Where charfield = 'WHATEVER'
And ((Datetime between '2014-02-01 00:00' AND '2014-02-01 23:59')
  OR (Datetime between '2014-02-02 00:00' AND '2014-02-02 23:59')
  OR (Datetime between '2014-02-03 00:00' AND '2014-02-03 23:59')
  OR (Datetime between '2014-02-04 00:00' AND '2014-02-04 23:59'))
```

But I only get data from the last range (`'2014-02-04'`), I don't know why. I'm certain that there are data in the other intervals too.

Please ignore the fact that the intervals are consecutive, it's just an example. In the real code, the intervals ranges are completely arbitrary.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you care about time, it's usually far more sensible to use a semi-open interval (inclusive start point, exclusive end point) and forgo the use of `BETWEEN` - i.e. `DateTime >= '20140201' and DateTime < '20140202'` would be your first range.

Comment: [It seems to work fine for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16ac0/1) - Are you sure there is data there? Is there more to your query that you have omitted to simplify it?

Comment: Are you passing that dates as string or as datetime typed variables? You can get some mistakes in implicit casting from a varchar

Comment: I've updated the query, including the extra bits I removed to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

> > When you are using BETWEEN and the column holds both date and time
> >     elements, what do you use as the end value? As you might realize, for
> >     different types, there are different precisions. What’s more, suppose
> >     that the type is DATETIME, and you use the following predicate.

```
WHERE
orderdate BETWEEN '20070201' AND '20070228 23:59:59.999'
```

> This type’s
>    precision is three and a third milliseconds. The milliseconds part of
>    the end point 999 is not a multiplication of the precision unit, so
>    SQL Server ends up rounding the value to midnight of March 1, 2007. As
>    a result, you may end up getting some orders that you’re not supposed
>    to see. In short, instead of BETWEEN, use >= and <, and this form will
>    work correctly in all cases, with all date and time types, whether the
>    time portion is applicable or not. Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012 tranining kit 70-461